# Jest AJAX unit testing not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jestjs

I am trying to test the following AJAX call using Jest (using https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html as a reference). The AJAX call should post to my web service and return JSON data, but the test fails with an error. The test is in main.test.js, and I am running it in the Package Manager Console (in Visual Studio) using: `npm test`.

I have tried implementing the AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest but the test still fails with the same error and I do not get any data back. I have also tried setting the parameter async: false, but this causes the test to hang without completing.

```
//main.js
function getData(handleData) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: '{choice:"'+option+'"}',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "WebServiceGrid.asmx/WebserviceFunction",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {                                     
            handleData(response);            
        },       
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },       
    });

    function handleData(response) {
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
//main.test.js
test('verifies getData returns data', done => {
    function handleData(data) {
        expect(data).toBe(/*some JSON data*/); 
        done();
    }
    getData(handleData);
}
```

`package.json (Jest setup)`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-editor-support": "^25.0.1"
}
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFiles": [
      "./source/setup-jest.js"
    ],
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles"
}
```

```js
//I am including jQuery in my setup-jest.js file:
const $ = require('jquery'); global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

I expect to get JSON data back from my web service but I am seeing the Jest test fail with the following error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout.

I have also tried increasing the Jest timeout to more than 5000ms but this did not seem to help

Comment: I don't see how `getData` would work on its own; you're declaring a `function handleData` inside it that will shadow the parameter of the same name. And your test is probably supposed to *call* `getData`, not declare it?

Comment: Also note that all of that code is server-side code, but jQuery is a client-side library; it runs in the browser. There's no `alert` with node either. Use [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) instead of `$.ajax`. Again, as far as I can tell, your main.js `getData` will not run properly at all; there's not much point in jesting code that's broken. Here's a minimal setup that works for me: https://pastebin.com/vs9krcMd

Comment: Sorry regarding your first comment  (And your test is probably supposed to call getData, not declare it?) that was a typo, that declaration should be handleData not getData (I fixed it). Regarding your second comment, I was actually able to write jest tests for and console out client-side jQuery commands (like jQuery selectors, length, select2, etc)?